# F11 Debug line by line only my .cpp?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an OpenCV application and I need to debug my code (Visual studio 2010, opencv with cmake).

I would like to debug line by line to see where exactly my app crashes. I am trying to use <kbd>F11</kbd> the problem is that <kbd>F11</kbd> shows me external code (opencv libraries, std libraries etc).

Is there any other way to don't put lots of breakpoint all over my code?

```
 int main(void) {
    vector<int> myVec;
    myVec.push_back(1);
    //> Do other stuff
 }
```

If I try <kbd>F11</kbd> with this code, visual studio will debug the vector library files too, and I want to  avoid that. I just want to follow the flow of the code inside my main();

Comment: Why don't you just let it crash and then look at the call stack?

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but maybe a small code snippet that illustrates it would help others? I would be interested in this if it were possible, but I doubt it is. (though to add it, the debugger would just ignore stepping into header files included with `<>` (and only step into ones included with `""`)... doubt a debugger does this though)

Comment: @Cornstalks: i have added a snippet, but I think the question is clear enough now

Comment: the following post describes how to avoid stepping into STL code. Maybe this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334414/auto-skip-stl-functions-during-step-by-step-debugging-in-msvc2010

Comment: @HolgerKretzschmar: that's interesting... But I can't believe that for such basic feature we need to edit registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi as already mentioned in my comment in VS2010 the only way to avoid stepping into STL code is to modify a registry key, as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334414/auto-skip-stl-functions-during-step-by-step-debugging-in-msvc2010).

With VS2012 there is another way by using [Visualizers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx?PageIndex=2).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go into external code (unless maybe showing it as assembly).

You should use <kbd>F10</kbd> to step to the next instead of going inside such a function.
You also can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to return to the next line (after the current function), if you are inside such external function code.

Comment: external code I meant file like: vector, xmemory, new.cpp, dbgmalloc.c and others that are showing up

Comment: I think his problem is doing something like trying to step into `myFunc("string")`. Hitting F11 will first take you into the `std::string` constructor (assuming that's what `myFunc()` takes).

Comment: @Cornstalks: yea you got the point, I would avoid to debug up to that files