# Problems with getting VS10 debugger to jump certain libs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, boost, regedit

I'm getting debugger errors when using the boost serilazation library. To fix these I am trying to get Visual Studio 10 to skip the debugging the boost library, after som reading I found out how this coult be achived but the solution somehow doesn't work. Here is a picture of the regedit.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g24tO.png (dont have enough reputation to post it inside)]

From what i've read this is the way to do it, but when debugging in VS10 it still gives me errors on boost files. Can someone see what i've done wrong?

EDIT

Found a problem with the solution, was in the 32bit part of regedit instead of 64 which my system is on. Changing this didn't however solve the problem. Here is a new picture.

[image]

Comment: Don't make us guess at the "errors".

Comment: For this the errors is quite irrelevant, I'm asking how to disable vs10 debugger to stop debugging the boost system. And with the settings shown above the debugger is still stepping into boost files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related post that will answer your question.
[How to skip common classes in VS 2008 when stepping in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062881/how-to-skip-common-classes-in-vs-2008-when-stepping-in)

You can do this by entering entries into the registry (I know, it sucks). The key you are looking for varies from 32 to 64 bit systems. For 32-bit systems the key is

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\NativeDE\StepOver

If you're running a 64 bit OS and a 32 bit Visual Studio the key is

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\NativeDE\StepOver

The Wow6432Node key is a key present for 32 bit applications running on 64 bit systems. (Sidenote: searching the registry for "_RTC_CheckEsp" probably will lead you to the right place, it's a default entry in Visual Studio 9)

The syntax should be familiar to you, but as an example, a simple entry could be string value boost::.*=NoStepInto which will avoid the debugger to step into Boost. See http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html for some other examples.