# Visual Studio debugger annoyance - Opening hidden/system files

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I was just wondering if there is anyway to stop Visual Studio 2008 from showing all of the files like iostream or xiosbase during debugging with a breakpoint?

I'm finding it really annoying and time consuming in having to watch files I would never touch  just because I'm printing out to console.

Thanks for looking,

Matt

Comment: isn't this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062881/how-to-skip-common-classes-in-vs-2008-when-stepping-in

Comment: It just does what you ask it to do.  Don't step-into code you don't want to debug, use the step-over command.  Use step-out when you accidentally step-into.  Memorize all three shortcut keystrokes and favor step-over first so you minimize the mistakes.